# itk Hessian3DToVesselnessMeasureImageFilter ,use of SetAlpha

Tags: visual-studio, itk

I am new to itk. I need to do vessel segmentation using itk. I didn't get why `SetAplha1` and `SetAlpha2` is used in itk Hessian3DToVesselnessMeasureImageFilter ? What is the role of this?

```
 using HessianFilterType = itk::HessianRecursiveGaussianImageFilter<ImageType>;
 HessianFilterType::Pointer hessianFilter = HessianFilterType::New();
hessianFilter->SetInput(filter_toitkimage->GetOutput());
hessianFilter->SetSigma(1.0);//does this will determine the spacing between each dicom image slices?


using VesselnessMeasureFilterType = itk::Hessian3DToVesselnessMeasureImageFilter<PixelType>;
VesselnessMeasureFilterType::Pointer vesselnessFilter = VesselnessMeasureFilterType::New();
vesselnessFilter->SetInput(hessianFilter->GetOutput());
vesselnessFilter->SetAlpha1(0.5);
vesselnessFilter->SetAlpha2(2.0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sigma` determines the scale of features. For example, a sigma of 1.0 will work on vessels about 2-3 mm in diameter, whereas a sigma of 5.0 will work best on vessels 10-15 mm in diameter (think aorta, vena cava).

Regarding the `Alpha` parameters, the [documentation](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Hessian3DToVesselnessMeasureImageFilter.html) says to see its description in [the authors' paper](http://www.spl.harvard.edu/archive/spl-pre2007/pages/papers/yoshi/).